# How can i compare values in pandas and change values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have some data frame, 
I have run this command:

```
share_df=df.iloc[:,60:61]
```

which make me a dataframe with one column with numbers,
now I want to run for loop on this share_df to see if the value bigger than the median then set it to 1 else set it to 0
this is the dataframe:

```
        shares
   0    593
   1    711
   2    1500
   3    1200
   4    505
   . .. ...
```

I want to compare  to median value so I made :

```
medianShareValue=share_df.median()
```

1.Question: when I do :

```
 for value in share_df:
   if value > medianShareValue:
       do something..
```

I get error:

**ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any()

or a.all().**

**------------------update-------------** for question number 2 this fixed my error:

```
share_df.columns=['shares']
```

2.Question:
when I try to change value in my dataframe i Get error
(same dataframe)

```
df_share.at[0, 'shares']=1
```

I get this df:

```
    shares  shares
0   593     1.0
1   711     NaN
2   150     NaN
3   1200    NaN
4   505     NaN
```

Which is obviously not what I need , I need to set and change the value and not create a new column

Comment: you can also perform the same while operating on a column using `np.where`: `share_df['new_column'] = np.where(share_df > medianShareValue,do_something,else_do_this)`

Answer (score 1):

Don't write a for loop in Python, that would be slow.

You can instead do

```
share_df["shares"] = (share_df["shares"] > medianShareValue).astype(int)
```

Comment: I did not understand your solution 
why not loop in on dataframe? , and how can I loop over my dataframe and check whether is something bigger or smaller than median and change it

Comment: Because it's gonna be slow :) Pandas have taken care of making operations such as this fast for you. When you do `share_df['shares']>medianShareValue`, you already comparing each element again `medianShareValue`, and you get a Series of `True` (if the element is greater than the median) and `False` otherwise

Comment: so what command should i run? I need to do  if its bigger than median change to 1 else change to 0

Comment: It doesnot help, it make all the rows become 0, What i need is to clasify bigger than median == to 1 else 0

Comment: @MaxBoyar what's your value of `medianShareValue`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pandas conditions. Imagine this is share_df

```
   shares
0   2
1   5
2   6
3   10
4   12
5   5
```

You have to run the following, which basically set a new column filled with 0 and place a 1 in every position where the value is bigger than the median.

```
medianShareValue=share_df.median()
# Define condition
BIGGER_THAN_MEDIAN = share_df["shares"]>median_value[0]

# Set new column with all values to 0
share_df.loc[:,"bigger_than_mean"] = 0

# Update values that are bigger than the median
share_df.loc[BIGGER_THAN_MEDIAN, "bigger_than_mean"]=1
```

And your output is:

```
    shares  bigger_than_median
0   2       0
1   5       0
2   6       1
3   10      1
4   12      1
5   5       0
```